# jetbrains-toolbox is unable to start from its desktop shortcut on GNOME, telling that "The name :1.686 was not provided by any .service files"

Tags: intellij-idea, debian, gnome, jetbrains-toolbox

Once I've installed *Jetbrains Toolbox* through a command:

```bash
sudo tar -xvf Téléchargements/jetbrains-toolbox-1.24.12080.tar.gz -C /opt
```

and a `chown` of its folder to my non-sudo user.

It worked well on *Debian 11*, until a week or two ago and now I'm unable to launch *jetbrains-tools* from its desktop shortcut on *GNOME*.

It fails silently and if look at the `/var/log/messages` they are telling this:

```
Jul 26 06:17:41 debian gnome-shell[390782]: Received error from D-Bus search provider org.gnome.seahorse.Application.desktop during GetResultMetas: Gio.DBusError: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name :1.686 was not provided by any .service files
Jul 26 06:17:41 debian gnome-shell[390782]: Wrong number of result metas returned by search provider org.gnome.seahorse.Application.desktop: expected 1 but got 0
```

mentioning that "*The name :1.686 was not provided by any .service files*"

What could it be?
the automate tool having for goal to update the whole *idea* software suite
stuck itself with an hard coded version, and is now unable to launch again?
That would be strange...

What's the way to solve that issue?

Comment: I have a similar problem and opened: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TBX-8042/Toolbox-unable-to-set-system-theme

Comment: Thanks, @s1ck. I think it will be useful if I [open an issue too for my problem](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TBX-8043/Jetbrain-toolbox-doesnt-launch-anymore-with-a-varlogmessage-The-name-1686-was-not-provided-by-any-service-files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, the solution given by Jetbrains for that issue, until it'll be resolved in 1.25 patch fixes, is:

to stop the `jetbrains-toolbox` process that automatically starts on session opening,
and to run it again from the menu,
at the time you're needing it to check the statuses of your softwares.

[image]